# Generate a Unique Key for Banking Transactions

Tags: php, algorithm, banking

I want to continuously import bank transactions via HBCI.
Problem is, that those neither have unique key, nor a exact time stamp (time stamp is only on day-resolution i.e. always 12AM).

This is the data I get from the API

[image]

Generating a hash over all fields would lead to false positives (if somebody transfers the same value at the same day with the same purpose text and so on)

How can I avoid duplicate imports and generate a unique key?

Comment: the obvious solution would be an autoincrement key.  BUT, i understand that you want to compose your unique key with data fields imported via hbci, and that would generate duplicates in case of multiple transactions with same value, on same date between the same local and remote accounts.  please confirm.

Comment: I can add an auto increment but still i have to identify which transactions I transferred already.

Comment: Got the same problem over here. I am thinking about simply counting the number auf statements of the same day. After all: if two statements are completely the same it does not matter which one you store first as long as you don't store it twice.

Comment: @Juergen: that's what I am doing in my answer, right? And there might be a completely same statement twice on the account sheet which should also be imported twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Generate a unique ID per transaction
 * We assume, that all transactions of a day are always present in the fetched transactions
 * (after a while, very old transactions might not appear)
 * So we generate a continues key per day, combine it with the date and have a globally unique key
 *
 * @return Transaction[]
 */
public static function getKeyedTransactions()
{
    $transactions = self::getTransactions();
    $result = [];
    $dateCounters = array();
    foreach($transactions as $transaction) {
        $date = $transaction->getDate()->format('Ymd');
        if (!isset($dateCounters[$date])) {
            $dateCounters[$date] = 0;
        }
        $dateCounters[$date]++;
        $uniqId = $date . sprintf('%05d', $dateCounters[$date]);
        $result[$uniqId] = $transaction;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I think: $date = $transaction->getBookingDate()->format('Ymd'); does the better job.